# splitting data using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file of many line. of format as below,

```
//many lines of normal text

      00.0000125  1319280   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
//lines of text
      0000011111      59   6.8  "$#*! My Dad Says" (2010) {You Can't Handle the Truce (#1.10)}
      1...101002      17   6.6  "$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime" (1986)
```

I want to split the data as columns `1...101002,17,6.6,"$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime" (1986)`

The program I tried is ,

```
import re
f = open("E:/file.list");
reg = re.compile('[+ ].{10,}[+ ][+0-9].{3,}[+ ]')
for each in f:
if reg.match(each):
    print each
    print reg.split(each)
```

It is not giving correct answer can I know the regex to use.

Comment: can you show your expected output ?

Comment: I have commented to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to match instead of split in this case.

```
^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/47

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"00.0000125 1319280 9.2 The Shawshank Redemption (1994)\n\n 0000011111 59 6.8 \"$#*! My Dad Says\" (2010) {You Can't Handle the Truce (#1.10)}\n 1...101002 17 6.6 \"$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime\" (1986)"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: `['', '0000000125', '1319280', '9.2', 'The', 'Shawshank', 'Redemption', '(1994)', '']` is the output I am getting for first line but i want `['0000000125', '1319280', '9.2', 'every thing else']`

Comment: Thank you. lines like this "Details on obtaining this posting via FTP are also given below". are also getting splitted. Is there away to avoid that?

Comment: @user168983 try `^\s*(?![a-zA-Z])(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text="""0000011111      59   6.8  "$#*! My Dad Says" (2010) {You Can't Handle the Truce (#1.10)}
...       1...101002      17   6.6  "$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime" (1986)"""
>>> re.findall(r'([0-9\.]+)\s*([0-9]+)\s*([0-9\.]+)\s*(".*")',text)
[('0000011111', '59', '6.8', '"$#*! My Dad Says"'), ('1...101002', '17', '6.6', '"$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime"')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed RegEx pattern.

```
import re
f = open("file.txt");

reg = re.compile(r"      (.{10}) *(\d*) *(\d*\.\d*) (.*)")
for each in f:
    if reg.match(each):
        print each
        print reg.split(each)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
>>> str='1...101002      17   6.6  "$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime" (1986)'
>>> re.findall(r'^([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+(.*)', str)
[('1...101002', '17', '6.6', '"$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime" (1986)')]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you split the lines by `split()` function then slice the split list (use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice))from leading of list to where that you have a number in parenthesis (`if re.match(r'\(\d+\)',j)`) :

```
>>> s="""0000011111      59   6.8  "$#*! My Dad Says" (2010) {You Can't Handle the Truce (#1.10)}"""
>>> s.split()
['0000011111', '59', '6.8', '"$#*!', 'My', 'Dad', 'Says"', '(2010)', '{You', "Can't", 'Handle', 'the', 'Truce', '(#1.10)}']
>>> l=s.split()
>>> [list(islice(l,0,i+1)) for i,j in enumerate(l) if re.match(r'\(\d+\)',j)]
[['0000011111', '59', '6.8', '"$#*!', 'My', 'Dad', 'Says"', '(2010)']]
```

If you have your lines in a list (read the file with `readlines()`) :

```
>>> lines = ["""00.0000125  1319280   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)""","""0000011111      59   6.8  "$#*! My Dad Says" (2010) {You Can't Handle the Truce (#1.10)}""", """1...101002      17   6.6  "$1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime" (1986)"""]

>>> [list(islice(line.split(),0,i+1)) for line in lines for i,j in enumerate(line.split()) if re.match(r'\(\d+\)',j)]
[['00.0000125', '1319280', '9.2', 'The', 'Shawshank', 'Redemption', '(1994)'], ['0000011111', '59', '6.8', '"$#*!', 'My', 'Dad', 'Says"', '(2010)'], ['1...101002', '17', '6.6', '"$1,000,000', 'Chance', 'of', 'a', 'Lifetime"', '(1986)']]
```